# Python Replacing Columns getting IndexError: index 8 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 8

Tags: python, replace, index-error

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here but I want to replace the initial column names with the respective name in column_names list.

```
column_names = ['FIPS','Admin2','Province_State','Country_Region','Last_Update','Lat','Long_','Confirmed','Deaths','Recovered','Active','Combined_Key']
df.columns = ['Province/State', 'Country/Region', 'Last Update', 'Confirmed',
       'Deaths', 'Recovered', 'Latitude', 'Longitude']

def replace_cols(df, new_columns):
    k = 0
    for i in df.columns:
        for j in column_names:
            seq = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,i, j).ratio()*100
            if seq >= 50:
                newcol = re.sub(i, j, i)
                df.columns.values[k] = newcol
                print(newcol)
                k += 1
```

Comment: could you also post df.head() ?

Comment: The problem is that the logic doesn't work. You calculate the difference between two columns and for Latitude it goes wrong. The difference between Latitude and Last_Update is bigger than 50 (increment of `k`) and continuing the for loop the diff between Latitude and Lat is bigger than 50 and `k` gets incremented again. The condition `seq >= 50` is risky.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the threshold from 50 to 54 works:

```py
import re

column_names = ['FIPS','Admin2','Province_State','Country_Region','Last_Update','Lat','Long_','Confirmed','Deaths','Recovered','Active','Combined_Key']
# df.columns = ['Province/State', 'Country/Region', 'Last Update', 'Confirmed','Deaths', 'Recovered', 'Latitude', 'Longitude']
cols = ['Province/State', 'Country/Region', 'Last Update', 'Confirmed','Deaths', 'Recovered', 'Latitude', 'Longitude']
df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=cols)


def replace_columns(df, new_columns):
    k = 0
    for i in df.columns:
        print('Old col', i, k)
        for j in column_names:
            seq = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,i, j).ratio()*100
            if seq >= 54:
                newcol = re.sub(i, j, i)
                print('Newcol ', newcol)
                df.columns.values[k] = newcol
                k += 1
    return df
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because Lat/Last_update both change the value Latitude (similarity more than 50%) so in the last loop your code first replaces Last_update, then Lat with latitude and then goes beyond the length of df.